# How to get last table generated with the method most efficient on mysql?

Tags: mysql

Ok I know that I can do this:

```
SELECT table_name  FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'myBDD' ORDER BY CREATE_TIME DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But Could do this most efficient?

### UPDATE:

No searched a efficient method.

### MY PROPOSAL SOLUTION:

I will generate the daily tables and delete them the next day by passing them to another read-only database to have a history, so I will be able to reduce my database and the query will be much more efficient.

#### Waiting some better...

Answer (score 0):

This is reasonably efficient. If your database contains tens of thousands of tables, it will take a while. But it's the best way to do what you want.

Comment: Yes,  but I need to generate two tables every time I start a game, when there are 10,000 games saved I have 20,000 tables generated, and the order by makes my query much slower but if there is nothing better I will have to look for another way to generate the tables, I guess I will generate the daily tables and delete them the next day by passing them to another read-only database to have a history, so I will be able to reduce my database and the query will be much more.